# lottie-react-native is not showing

Tags: react-native, lottie-react-native

I tried many times but it's not showing

i want to show and resolve this problem,

here are my code

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: '100%' }}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Helo World</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <LottieView
          source={require('./PoliteChicky.json')}
          style={{width: '100%'}}
          autoPlay
          loop
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

export default App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your **package.json** file ,

```js
"lottie-react-native": "^5.1.5",
```

Import this in your desired file

```js
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
```

Use the LottieView as follows in your desired page

```js
  <LottieView
                  source={images.searchloading}
                  style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                  autoPlay
                  loop
                />
```

Comment: I think the issue is based on the width You had given

Comment: Thank you so much,  Bala Vigness, it's a version issue!

Answer (score 0):

He Goku Sama, i've something like this and works, please try to create a folder inside your src folder like image bellow and place the json from lottie inside. If this doesn't works, can you share your project on  github so we can take a better look on it.

[image]

This is a lottie animation:
[image]

Comment: I tried what you provided, but It's still not showing!

Comment: can you please provider an github repo to take a look on your code?